# what is an example of blackbody?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Aside from a cavity with a small hole, what are the examples of blackbody we observe in our daily lives? For example, if we heat up a chunk of copper and record the emitted radiation, would that spectral distribution be described by the plank's radiation law? is the plank's radiation law only for blackbodies which absorbs all radiation incident on it? or is it for anything that's heated?

If we heat up a chunk of something made of only one type of element, wouldn't the spectral distribution be discrete since atoms absorb and emit photons with only certain energies?

Comment: People are black-body radiators. Even whites. That is how they check for corona fever.

Comment: It doesn't need to heated. Cold things like event horizons and the CMB are very close to black body. Hot things like the center of the Earth, Jupiter, Sun, core collapse supernova or a freshly imploded plutonium pit are probably very close too. There also the space-borne microwave radiometer which is tuned to Earth's thermal emission into space at "medium" temps.

Comment: @Pieter people aren't perfect black bodies, a perfect black body is one which absorbs all kinds of radiation, people reflect a lot of visible radiation

Comment: @SKDash Reflection in the visible is irrelevant as there is no emission in the visible at body temperatures. People radiate a decent approximation of the black-body spectrum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cosmic Microwave Background is the most perfect black body that have been observed - it has near ideal Planck spectrum at temperature of 2.7 K.

Assuming the theoretical prediction that black holes emit Hawking radiation, it would also be a black body radiation, but it was never observed.

Stars emit almost-black body radiation, but their spectrum contains the spectral lines of the elements present in the star.

No physical object absorbs all wavelengths of ligt completely, so none is a black body and none emits a perfect black body radiation. Still, there are some materials that are pretty close, for example some carbon nanotube arrays can absorb 99.9% of light.

Answer (score 2):

The Sun is not a bad approximation to a blackbody radiator.

A blackbody radiator must be capable of absorbing light at all wavelengths and should be in thermal equilibrium. The Sun matches this description reasonably well, the problem is that the depth from which light escapes the Sun is somewhat wavelength-dependent, and because the Sun isn't isothermal and gets hotter with depth, it does not emit a perfect blackbody spectrum.

Other objects may have a spectrum that looks a bit like a blackbody, but with less overall power emitted. Such objects, "grey bodies", have a less-than perfect, but almost wavelength-independent absorption coefficient.

If the absorption coefficient consisted of discrete lines, with gaps, then this could not be a blackbody, since it would not be a perfect absorber at all wavelengths.

In practice, there is always *some* continuum absorptivity, so providing the object is thick enough, then it can still be a blackbody.

There are lots of duplicate questions on Physics SE which explain what microscopic processes might lead to some continuous absorption in solids or gases.

Comment: Is the sun a blackbody deep in the photosphere, and that spectrum is modified by the time it reaches Earth?

Comment: The spectrum emitted by the Sun is basically blackbody emission arising at different depths (and temperatures) depending on wavelength. The continuum comes from the deepest layers visible, whereas light at the bottom of an absorption line arise from higher, cooler layers. @JEB

Comment: so that part of the sun is in fact a blackbody, it's just that we do not have a direct view of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of everyday objects which furnish good examples of blackbody radiation, or something very close to it, as follows.

The electric heat coil in the surface of an electric stove, the filament in a conventional car headlight, the red-hot wires in an electric space heater, and the glowing catalytic grid in a kerosene-fired space heater are all good approximations to a blackbody.

Note that the emission spectrum of for example a glowing-hot object in equilibrium with its surroundings won't have discrete emission lines in it because the vibrations of the charges in its surface (which produce the radiation it emits) exist in a distribution and generally do not involve ionization and recombination effects.

A notable exception to this is the *mercury vapor lamp* which produces an emission spectrum with spikes in the UV, green, and blue superimposed on a blackbody background.

Comment: Classically, EM-radiation is caused by the acceleration of electrically charged objects (like electrons, ions and protons). In quantumphysics EM-radiation is explained by transitions between energylevels of atoms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. 
But can you answer this one:
If we heat up a chunk of something made of only one type of element, wouldn't the spectral distribution be discrete since atoms absorb and emit photons with only certain energies?

Comment: I guess you answered your question perfectly ;-)